# How to save a Dictionary of Dictionaries to UserDefaults [Int:[Int:Int]]?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am trying to save a dictionary of dictionaries to UserDefaults.

I can save the dictionary in this way:

```
var dict = [Int:[Int:Int]]()
dict[1] = [4:3]
dict[10] = [5:10]

let data = try 
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict, requiringSecureCoding: false)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "dict")
```

But when I try to retrieve it:

```
if let data2 = defaults.object(forKey: "dict") as? NSData {
let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [Int:[Int:Int]], from: data2)
print(dict)
}
```

I get an error: Cannot convert value of type '[Int : [Int : Int]].Type' to expected argument type '[AnyClass]' (aka 'Array')

Is there a way to store a [Int:[Int:Int]] Dictionary in UserDefaults? Or I have to use other aproach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` to do the encoding, since `Dictionary<Int,Dictionary<Int,Int>>` conforms to `Codable`.

```
var dict = [Int:[Int:Int]]()
dict[1] = [4:3]
dict[10] = [5:10]

let encodedDict = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dict)

UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedDict, forKey: "dict")
let decodedDict = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Int:[Int:Int]].self, from: UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "dict")!) //[10: [5: 10], 1: [4: 3]]
```

Don't use force unwrapping when working with real values rather than these hard coded ones.

Comment: Better to save the data to a separate json file. It doesn't make any sense inserting it inside a plist file

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, I wouldn't necessarily save it to `UserDefaults` either, but it doesn't really do any harm and OP was asking how to save to `UserDefaults`. Using `PropertyListEncoder` instead of `JSONEncoder` also works too for saving into `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried with swift 4.1, And following method worked fine.**

```
    var dict = [Int:[Int:Int]]()
    dict[1] = [4:3]
    dict[10] = [5:10]

    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "dict")
```

**Retrieving:**

```
    if let data2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "dict") as? Data {
        let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data2)
        if let dic = dict as? [Int:[Int:Int]] { print(dic) }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but these methods are deprecated in iOS 12:

'archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead
'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead


And if I use the non-deprecated methods, I get these error: Cannot convert value of type '[Int : [Int : Int]].Type' to expected argument type '[AnyClass]' (aka 'Array<AnyObject.Type>')

Comment: Note that you can use UserDefaults `data(forKey:)` method instead of using object(forKey:) and casting from Any to Data